# ¿Qué significa el comando class en HTML?

Tags: html, css

Buenas estoy intentando montar una pagina web desde una plantilla pero quiere introducirme mas en el diseño de la pagina y necesito saber qué significa ese comando porque en esta plantilla me salen cosas como esta y la verdad que no entiendo mucho:

```
<header>
    <div class="row-top">
        <div class="main">
            <div class="wrapper">
```

o :

```
<div class="row-bot">
        <div class="row-bot-bg">
            <div class="main">
```

y tambien:

```
<div class="slider-wrapper">
                    <div class="slider">
                        <ul class="items">
```

Comment: <div class="slider-wrapper">
                        <div class="slider">
                            <ul class="items">

Comment: asin son las cosas que me salen y la verdad q no las entiendo

Comment: Bueno, hay que empezar por el principio: 1. **Java y Javascript no es lo mismo** ¿De cuál de los dos estás hablando? 2. Tu pregunta no se entiende, pon fragmentos de tu código con respecto a las dudas que tienes. 3. ¿Ya leíste algo de la documentación del lenguaje del cual tienes dudas?

Comment: @A.Cedano los fragmentos de código estaban ahi, lo que pasa es que al no estar bien indentados no aparecían. Por otro lado,he quitado la etiqueta java ya que es obvio que no se refería a eso. De hecho,probablemente sea mas bien html y css

Comment: Gracias @Pikoh En efecto, se trata de CSS / HTML. [Aquí hay un poco de documentación en castellano al respecto](http://librosweb.es/libro/css/capitulo_2/selectores_basicos.html).

Comment: He propuesto la corrección del título de java a HTML, ya que seguramente el usuario se ha confundido. Aún que quizás también habría que cambiar lo de comando por atributo.

Comment: Mira esta [guia](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. Tambien, aprovecha y haz el [tour](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender mejor como funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Comment: @Xerif creo que sería injusto dejar fuera del título a CSS: _¿Qué significa el atributo class en HTML / CSS?_ podría ser.

Comment: Pues si @A. Cedano , ya que su principal funcion es el enlazado a css. Aún que sigo insistiendo lo de comando no se termina de adaptar, seria más correcto decir atributo.

Comment: @Xerif: Quitar comando del título de la pregunta sería cambiar la intención original del OP en la que es patente que no está claro las cosas básicas de HTML. En lo que respecta a incluir CSS en el título, también considero que cambiaría la intención original del OP. Si bien ya se ha "intervenido" para corregir el formato de la pregunta para que se muestren las líneas de HTML y el corregir las etiquetas y título, el agregar además CSS me parece que sería excesivo. Siento que se le estaría arrebatando la pregunta al OP.

Answer (score 4):

#### `class`

hace referencia a un selector de clase, que se puede atribuir a todos los elementos de un HTML para luego aplicar estilos a los elementos marcados con esa clase usando hojas de estilo o CSS a través [class selectors](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/CSS/Class_selectors) o usando Javascript a través de funciones  [`Document.getElementsByClassName()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName).

Es decir, que CSS trabaja junto con HTML, Javascript... y se puede combinar el uso de los tres.

La [documentación de MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/Class_selectors) dice lo siguiente:

> En un documento HTML, los selectores de clase buscan un elemento
>   basado en el contenido de su atributo class. El atributo class está
>   definido como una lista de elementos separados por espacio, y uno de
>   esos elementos debe coincidir exactamente con el nombre de clase dado
>   en el selector.

`class` pertenece a los [atributos globales](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/HTML/Atributos_globales) de HTML:

> Los atributos globales son atributos comunes a todos los elementos
>   HTML; pueden usarse en todos los elementos, aunque pueden no tener
>   efecto en algunos de ellos.

Usando en un documento HTML etiquetas como `class="nombre-clase"`, puedes modificar de forma automática, en pocas línea de código, el estilo de todos los elementos que tengan dicha clase usando CSS. Dichas modificaciones pueden hacerse  también usando Javascript.

La ventaja, aparte de poderlos alcanzar todos desde el mismo lugar (CSS), tener documentos HTML más limpios, código menos redundante, mejor organizado... es que puedes introducir modificaciones posteriores sin tener que recorrer todo el contenido de tu HTML modificando. Y si entra en juego Javascript, puedes modificar contenido de forma dinámica mediante clases con una facilidad asombrosa.

Supongamos una página con miles o millones de documentos HTML. Puedes aplicar estilos en ellos de varias formas.

#### **forma 1:**

Aplicando estilos directamente a los elementos, mediante la etiqueta `style`:

```
<p style="color:red;">Texto en rojo</p>
<p style="color:red;">Otro texto en rojo</p>
```

**forma 2:**

Aplicando estilos mediante hojas de estilo CSS:

Tendrías esto en el CSS:

```
.rojo {
   color:red;
}
```

Y esto en el HTML:

```
<p class="rojo">Texto en rojo con nombre de clase y CSS</p>
<p class="rojo">Otro texto en rojo con nombre de clase y CSS</p>
```

Supongamos que tienes miles de documentos con texto como en la forma uno, y luego hay necesidad de que además de aparecer en rojo, tiene que aparecer también en negritas.

Para hacer ese cambio en la forma 1, tendrías que ir buscando en tus miles de documentos cada etiqueta y modificarla cada una de la forma siguiente:

```
 <p style="color:red; font-weight: bold;">Texto en rojo</p>
 <p style="color:red; font-weight: bold;">Otro texto en rojo</p>
```

Para hacerlo en la forma 2, sólo tendrías que agregar una línea al CSS:

```
  font-weight: bold;
```

Esta es sólo una, entre muchas ventajas del uso de `class`.

Las hojas de estilo se enlazan con el documento HTML, colocando el estilo directamente en el encabezado del HTML, usando la etiqueta `<style>` o enlazando el documento HTML con un documento CSS, mediante la etiqueta `<link>`.

---

**Ejemplo de código:**

Aunque verás que el resultado es el mismo, el mantenimiento es diferente, sobre todo cuando hay que introducir o quitar algo nuevo en el estilo.

```css
.rojo {
        color:red;
        font-weight:bold;
        }
```

```html
Forma 1

<p style="color:red; font-weight: bold;">Texto en rojo</p>
<p style="color:red; font-weight: bold;">Otro texto en rojo</p>
   
<hr />Forma 2
   
 <p class="rojo">Texto en rojo mediante CSS</p>
 <p class="rojo">Otro texto en rojo mediante CSS</p>
```

---

Esto es lo básico.

Puedes tener más información en la documentación de CSS, de HTML. Puedes ver también [este enlace](http://html.conclase.net/w3c/html401-es/present/styles.html).

En páginas como [codepen](https://codepen.io/projects/) puedes ver ejemplos de millones de cosas que se pueden hacer combinando HTML+CSS o HTML+CSS+Javascript.

Comment: Añadiría simplemente por completar que class es uno de los atributos globales y puede ser agregado a cualquier etiqueta.  https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/HTML/Atributos_globales  por lo demás perfecto, te dejo mis puntos

Comment: Gracias @Xerif he agregado tu sugerencia.

Answer (score 1):

La pregunta en realidad trata sobre el **[atributo global class](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/HTML/Atributos_Globales/class)** de las etiquetas HTML, no sobre un comando.

Un [atributo global](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/HTML/Atributos_Globales/) puede usarse en todos los elementos HTML.

En el caso particular class se utiliza en CSS y en funciones del elementos del DOM. Por ejemplo, pude usarse [document.getElementsByClassName](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName) para seleccionar todos los elementos de una clase determinada para luego hacer algo con ellos. En CSS se utiliza en [selectores de clase](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Class_selectors) para dar formato a los elementos de una clase determinada.

Answer (score 0):

El class adentro del div, se utiliza para que el navegador sepa que estilo dentro del CSS debe aplicar a ese item.

Ojo, porque los class se pueden anidar, pq si un item tiene un class, y un hijo de este tiene otro class, y tienen propiedades que se sobreescriben, se utilizara siempre la ultima class encontrada.